# Customising Search Box in My site in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

is it possible to customize search box in mysite of SharePoint 2013 ?

Default
[image]

My requirement
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can explore changing the Control Template that is used by the search box, but you may be better off creating an "Advanced People Search" page or app that you link to from the My Site Host.

Comment: can u explain more? right now I am unable to search anything from the default search box.what I am doing wrong? I need to setup something?

Comment: Are you saying that you have no results? If that is the case you need to Set up the User Profile Service, Populate the Profiles and then Crawl them from the Search Service Application.

Comment: I tried configuring search service application in central admin.followed everything as per this article but still no results foundhttp://amsharingpoints.blogspot.in/2013/11/start-search-service-application-crawl.html

Comment: What are you seeing in the crawl logs? Do you have a User Profile Service? Did you create Content Source for the User Profile Service?

Comment: Yes I created everything

Comment: And the crawl logs? Do you have sps3 success entries?